# Commutation of Convolution, Restriction and Differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $B$ be the open unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$ centered at zero and let $K=\bar{B}\cap (\mathbb R^{n-1}\times\{0\})$. Suppose you are given $u\in C^{1,\alpha}(B)$ such that $u|_K=f\in C^2(K)$. For a standard symmetric mollifier $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(B)$, let $u^\varepsilon = u*\varphi^\varepsilon$, where $\varphi^\varepsilon(x):=\varphi(x/\varepsilon)\varepsilon^{-n}$.

I would like to show a convergence $\partial_{ij}^2 u^\varepsilon \to \partial_{ij}^2f$, where $i,j\ne n$. Is such a result available? I'm interested in something pointwise at least but I have no idea how to tackle this question.

Comment: Hi, there is a result that says if $\phi$ is smooth and $f$ is $L^1$, then $\phi\ast f$ is smooth, with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\phi\ast f) = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\phi)\ast f$. I think applying this twice would give your result.

Comment: I don't see how this applies here. One must still show that $\partial_{ij}^2(\phi^\varepsilon*u)|_K \to \partial_{ij}^2f$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$. Generally one can say $\partial_{ij}^2(\phi*u)=(\partial_{ij}^2\phi)*u=\phi*(\partial_{ij}^2u)$ but $\partial_{ij}^2u$ is in $L^2$ and has no trace on $K$...